# custom subroutine for WebDriverWait.until throws an error

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am testing an angular web-app using selenium and python. For my test, I am setting up some data using API calls. Now I want to wait until the data shows up in the front-end before proceeding with my test. We currently have a 60 second wait to overcome this problem; however, I was hoping for a smarter wait and wrote the following code:

```
def wait_for_plan_to_appear(self,driver,plan_locator):

    plan_name_element = UNDEF

    try:
        self.navigateToPlanPage()
        plan_name_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(plan_locator)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

    return plan_name_element

def find_plan_name_element(self,plan_id):

    plan_locator = '//*[@data-hraf-id="'+plan_id+'-plan-name"]'
    plan_name_element = UNDEF
    try:
        plan_name_element = WebDriverWait(self.driver,60,2).until(self.wait_for_plan_to_appear(self.driver,plan_locator))
    except TimeoutException:
        self.logger.debug("Could not find the plan with plan_id = "+plan_id)
    return plan_name_element
```

In my test script, I am calling:

```
self.find_plan_name_element('e7fa25a5-0b39-4a97-b99f-44c48439ce99') # the long string is the plan-id
```

However, when I run this code - i get following error:

```
error: 'int' object is not callable"
```

If I change the wait_for_plan_to_appear such that it returns a boolean, it throws error:

```
error: 'bool' object is not callable"
```

Has someone seen/resolved this in their work ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use `"...".format()` to automatically convert the plan_id to a string.
Moreover you could simplify the waiter by using an expected condition :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException

class element_loaded_and_displayed(object):
    """ An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a
    page and visible. Refreshes the page if the element is not present.
    returns the WebElement once it is located and visible.
    """
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)
            return element if element.is_displayed() else False
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False
        except NoSuchElementException as ex:
            driver.refresh()
            raise ex

def find_plan_name_element(self, plan_id):
    plan_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-hraf-id='{0}-plan-name']".format(plan_id))
    err_message = "Could not find the plan with plan_id = {0}".format(plan_id)

    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout=60, poll_frequency=2)
    return wait.until(element_loaded_and_displayed(plan_locator), err_message)
```

Comment: Thanks Florent. However, I made the suggested change (about using .format() )and I am still getting the same error.

I cannot use EC.visibility_of_element_located , because I need to refresh the page each time before checking if the element shows up in the list. Is there any way to enforce page refresh before checking for element visibility using EC ? If I do use EC, then this error disappears; however it does not solve my problem , since sometimes the element is not available on the first time that the page is navigated to and needs several page refreshes.